# SQL Query between 3 tables that related by ids

Tags: sql

I have a 3 Tables like this:

Table 1: Category (ID, Description)
Table 2: SubCategory (ID, Description, CategoryParent_ID)
Table 3: Items (ID, SubCategory_ID, Info, Documentation, etc...)

where SubCategory_ID in items table refers to SubCategory Table, & this last one refers to Category Table by CategoryParent_ID.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMSED.jpg)

I want to make a query, that:
When I select a Category from Table 1, Every item in **Table 3** that related to this Category is shown (via SubCategory)
Example: I select IT Equipment from table 1
data shown must be: Every item in table 3 that is related to Table 2 AND Table 2 get its reference from TABLE 1

Comment: Google SQL join.

Comment: Hint: join ... have you tried a query yet?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text, not images. Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Homework? Remember that you won't learn much if we do it for you.

Comment: not Homework Man :) just confused with too many Query possibilities :)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to look into joins.

`SELECT *
FROM tableOne, tableTwo, tableThree
WHERE tableOne.ID = tableTwo.CategoryParent_ID AND tableTwo.ID = tableThree.SubCategory_ID`

You can also avoid these joins in the "where" clause by explicitly placing them in the "from" clause.

For example (jarlh's way):

`SELECT *
FROM tableOne
INNER JOIN tableTwo ON tableOne.ID = tableTwo.CategoryParent_ID
INNER JOIN tableThree ON tableTwo.ID = tableThree.SubCategory_ID`

Here's some info:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: @jarlh Yea I agree

Comment: ur help would be appreciated @jarlh

Comment: It works this way:
SELECT * FROM Table3
Left Outer JOIN Table2 ON Table3.SubCategory_ID = Table2.ID
Where [Table2.CategoryParent_ID] = Table1.ID

Comment: @Afif No problem, the version I wrote up there gave results from all tables. That outer join you have will let you only show results from the left table, which is what you want (I assume).